# Simultaneous NSUserNotification Alerts On Mountain Lion

Tags: nsnotificationcenter, osx-mountain-lion, nsusernotification

I'm attempting to create New Email alerts (via AppleScript and a Cocoa app) for Outlook 2011 that display through the ML Notification Center.

It's 90% there, the only issue is that when more than 1 email arrives at a time, the second alert quickly overwrites the first one.

I'm getting the feeling that this is by design and that the Notification Center doesn't permit more than one alert on the screen at a time (unlike Growl which will send an array of alerts down your screen) because the code seems rather straightforward.

If anyone has any insight on this please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Apple Mail combines multiple simultaneous notifications into one which displays the total number of new messages. You may wish to try that approach.

Comment: This is ideal, however it's a bit tricky considering the manner in which the script is executed, and in the event there's only 2-3 emails I'd prefer them all to display.

Do you know if there's any thing specific you have to do programmatically - or if it's even possible - to have multiple alerts (from the same app) appear simultaneously, cascading down the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Note that while in Mountain Lion it is still not possible (I think) in 10.9 and above there is a new attribute, [identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSUserNotification/identifier), that allows you to show more than one notification at once (as long as the identifier is different)